# Bonferroni corrected p-values that exceed 1: possible or non-sense?

Tags: p-value, bonferroni

My question concerns the Bonferroni correction of p-values. In my analysis, I would like to multiply the obtained p-values by *N*, where *N* is the chosen number for the Bonferroni correction, such as 2, 3, 4, ..., N. Hence, I would not like to divide the p-thresholds by N, as it is often done.

However, the multiplication of p-values by a certain factor can lead to p-values that exceed 1.

I have seen people debating over p-values that exceed 1 due to the multiplcation of the obtained p-values, but there is no consensus if that makes sense or if p-values > 1 are always and in every case meaningless. Furthermore, I read that software packages, like SPSS, automatically limit the p-values to 1 in this case.

Could somebody please explain if p-values should always be limited to 1 even though they can mathematically exceed 1 when multiplied by a certain factor due to Bonferroni correction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whether you divide the thresholds by a number or multiply the $p$ values by the same number is mathematically completely equivalent:

$$ p\leq \frac{\alpha}{N} \quad\iff\quad Np\leq\alpha. $$

So there is no cause for concern if you get values $Np\geq 1$ in the inequality on the right.

Also, it makes no difference, whether your adjusted $p$ value is $1$ or larger, since you won't reject the null hypothesis in either case.

Actually, I would simply report the original $p$ values and note which ones remain significant *after correction*.

Comment: Thank you, Stephan. What you say makes sense to me.

Comment: If it is so, please upvote the answer and accept it by clicking the tick alongside the post.

Comment: Personally I haven't encountered this idea of "correcting the p-value" before. To me it's rather weird and meaningless to do so, and produces nonsenses like p > 1. I'd always simply correct the significance level.